# Trying to upload a Godot game to Google Play

Tags: upload, google-play, apk, release, godot

I've created a game in Godot, and I'm trying to upload it to Google Play to release in a few days. I made sure the app wasn't in debug mode and I created an upload key with android studio and I believe Godot does the signing with it for me. When I go to upload the game, however, Google presents me with this:

> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

I've looked everywhere on here, reddit, youtube, godot docs, etc. but nothing has helped me solve the issue.

1) What does the error mean and 
2) How do I fix it? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you specify the path to the release keystore along with the key name and password in the Android export preset?
Also, to export in release mode, you need to uncheck **Export with Debug** at the bottom of the file dialog that appears when you choose the export path. It's a bit hidden, so pay attention to it.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure of all of that